# Javadoc @link references in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, javadoc

I'm trying to generate some Javadocs with Android Studio. I'm referring with `{@link #method()}` a method in the same class as the link but I still get a `reference not found` error from Javadoc. I'm probably omitting something very stupid but I cannot figure out what it is. Has anybody else come across the same problem?

Comment: A bug report has been filed - seems to be a similar - though it is related to auto-complete but you might get some additional info there:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67855

Answer (score 46):

In Android Studio within a javadoc comment, try typing `{@` and then hitting <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> to see what pops up...

After choosing `link`, hit <kbd>space</kbd>.

Now try <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> again for a list of all possible classes.

To just make a reference to a method/data within the current class, type <kbd>#</kbd> and then <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> to see a list of probably-what-you-want.

Don't forget to make sure the brackets are closed!

Comment: and how to reference an XML file? something like `{@link res/custom_strings.xml}`

Comment: @Rexxar: Don't know, but that's a very good question! Go ahead and make it a separate question and post the link here for others.

Comment: Thank you for your words of understanding and encouragement! Here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41433645/how-to-reference-an-xml-file-in-android-javadoc

Comment: Any chances you would know how to link build.gradle file in comments?

Comment: @RahulKhurana That's a really good question!  You should make your own question.  That way other people can easily find it.

Comment: thanks @ScottBiggs i did posted a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49483931/4079010). Let me know if you figure out a way to link gradle file in the post.

Comment: for XML layout = {@link R.layout#activity_main}, drawable  {@link R.drawable#ic_television} and so on.

Answer (score 24):

The format for the javaDoc lint tag in Android Studio is:

```
{@link package.class#member label}
```

Here is more information on [javaDoc tags](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_documentation.htm).

Comment: because it doesn't fix the problem why these show up.

long explanation is that when you extend a view and override methods in android studio and choose to add the javadoc for the overridden methods then the links in them don't include the package name in the link. and android studio drows a fit over it and you have to manually fix them with some search & replace.

so for example see android.view.View#View(Context, AttributeSet, int, int) is imported into your view extending class as see #View(Context, AttributeSet, int, int), and you need to fix manually.

Comment: Any chances you would know how to link build.gradle file in comments?

Answer (score 13):

I don't know if anyone is still struggling with it but if you are and `{@link` is not working then make sure your comment block looks something like this

```
/**
* {@link 'your reference'
*/
```

make sure that the comment block starts with two `*` and not one, apparently, this works for me in the android studio.

Comment: this is very important for someone who is new to documentation in Android Studio, as for Android Studio will not recognize @link command...